# Should I use Constructor Injection or IoC.Resolve?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm building very simple board game (just to learn some new stuff). It will be cross-platform (written using Xamarin). I've already written the core of the game, but I'm not sure (still) whether should I use **constructor injection** or **IoC resolve**. Right now I use **IoC.Resolve** and then pass through parameter.

Here is my code. I have `Game` that has 2 dependencies and type. I have factories to create Games and Players:

**Abc.MyGame.Domain**

- Interfaces

  ```
  public interface IGame
  {
      GameType GameType { get; }
      IGameBoard GameBoard { get; }
      List<IPlayer> Players { get; }

      // Other stuff...
  }

  public interface IGameBoard
  {
      //board stuff...
  }

  public interface IPlayer
  {
      int PlayerId { get; set; }
      PlayerType PlayerType { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Factory interfaces

  ```
  public interface IGameFactory
  {
      IGame CreateGame(GameType type, IGameBoard board);
  }

  public interface IPlayerFactory
  {
      IPlayer CreatePlayer(PlayerType type, int id);
  }
  ```
- Factories

  ```
  public class GameFactory : IGameFactory
  {
      public IGame CreateGame(GameType type, IGameBoard board)
      {
          switch (type)
          {
              case GameType.SinglePlayer:
                  return new MyGame(type, board,
                      new List<IPlayer> { CreateHuman(1), CreateBot(2) });
              case GameType.TwoPlayers:
                  return new MyGame(type, board,
                      new List<IPlayer> { CreateHuman(1), CreateHuman(2) });
              case GameType.Online:
                  return new MyGame(type, board,
                      new List<IPlayer> { CreateHuman(1), CreateOnlinePlayer(2) });

          }
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```

Then, there is an API. Used by UI:

**Abc.MyGame.API**

```
public class GameAPI
{
    public IGame CurrentGame { get; set; }

    public IGame CreateGame(IGameFactory gameFactory, GameType type, IBoard board)
    {
        CurrentGame = gameFactory.CreateGame(type, board);
        return CurrentGame;
    }

    // Other stuff, like make move etc...
}
```

... and my UI:

**Abc.MyGame.UI.WinForms**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private GameAPI api = new GameAPI();
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Load all dependencies
        var modules = new List<INinjectModule> { new GameModule() };
        kernel.Load(modules);
    }

    private void buttonStartGame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IGameBoard board = kernel.Get<IGameBoard>(
            new ConstructorArgument("width", 7), 
            new ConstructorArgument("height", 6)
        );

        api.CreateGame(kernel.Get<IGameFactory>(), GameType.TwoPlayers, board);
    }
}
```

I need to `IGameBoard` in my `IGame`. ONLY there. I need to inject board and players to `IGame`.

**Here is my problem/question:**
Do I really need to resolve `IGameBoard` at the very "front" of my program? I resolve it in `UI`, when somebody click "Start Game" button. And then I pass this board through `API`, then I pass it to `GameFactory`, then I pass it to `Game` constructor (finally!). Is it a bad practice to create (or resolve) `IPlayerFactory` and `IGameBoard` inside `GameFactory`? `API.CreateGame` will have only `type` parameter in that case? I mean for specific GameFactory there is only one board (evey time the same), so I'm not sure I need to create board at the very beginning...

EDIT:
MyGame constructor:

```
public class MyGame : IGame
{
    public IBoard Board { get; }
    public GameType Type { get; }
    public List<IPlayer> Players { get; }

    public MyGame(GameType type, IBoard board, List<IPlayer> players)
    {
        Type = type;
        Board = board;
        Players = players;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if you should use Constructor injection vs. Property injection or injection vs resolving from within the object?

Comment: @DStanley Constructor injection vs resolving from within the object. Should I resolve `IGameBoard` in UI project and inject resolved instance via constructor through `GameAPI`, `GameFactory` to `Game` OR... just resolve it within the object in `GameFactory` while creating `MyGame`?

Comment: The short answer is that you should **favour Constructor Injection** over other patterns; particularly over [Service Locator, which is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern). It's not clear why you have to pass `board` through layers, though. Why does `GameAPI.CreateGame` take `IGameBoard` as an argument? Why does `IGameFactory.CreateGame`? (And why is `GameAPI.GameFactory` a settable property?)

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'm aware of Service Locator anit-pattern. That's why I asked this question. 

*why you have to pass board through layers?* - Because, when I call `api.CreateGame`, I know it depends on board (it needs board). I could skip that, and create board via `new` in `GameFactory.CreateGame` - but I think it'd be bad. 

*why does GameAPI.CreateGame take IGameBoard as an argument?*
- I need a board to create a game. Isn't it Constructor Injection?

Comment: @MarkSeemann *And why is GameAPI.GameFactory a settable property?* - sorry, that was a mistake. I fixed it. **CurrentGame** is used later in the class  for: CurrentGame.MakeMove etc..

Comment: *Isn't it Constructor Injection?* There's no Constructor Injection to be seen anywhere in your code examples. All the constructors shown are parameterless.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Now I'm really confused:/ What about `IGame CreateGame(GameType type, IGameBoard board);` ? I inject board through interface, right? Then I create concrete game - `MyGame` with constructor that takes this board -` MyGame(type, board,...)`. I was confident that this is *Constructor Injection*, now I don't know nothing:/

Comment: You haven't shown the `MyGame` constructor...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Sorry, I added it. I basically have 3 *layers*. UI (*Form1.cs*), API (*GameAPI.cs*), Domain's Factory and Domain's Entity (*MyGame.cs*). The goal, is to create **MyGame** which has Type (single player, multi, via wifi, etc..), Players and Board. My idea was to inject players and board into the Game. I'm not sure if it's good to create IBoard instance at the very beginning (in Form1.cs), injecting it to GameAPI, which will inject it to GameFactory, WHICH will inject it MyGame constructor?

Comment: Why is `IGameBoard` part of the interface defintion of `IGameFactory.CreateGame`?

Comment: Sorry that I can't help you any better, but I tried copying your code into Visual Studio, in order to refactor it, but I couldn't even get it to compile without too much guesswork... Please consider supplying a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @MarkSeemann Sorry! I've uploaded very simple prototype here: https://github.com/toddenglewood/tictactoe It's very simple and clean

Comment: @MarkSeemann I posted question on CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111345/ioc-resolve-deep-in-the-project-or-constructor-injection-on-entry-point-of-app Maybe there, I described my concerns a little bit better

Answer (score 0):

> Do I really need to resolve IGameBoard at the very "front" of my program?

Yes, dependencies need to be resolved at entry points and at the start of lifetime scopes (if any) in your application. Often, this is abstracted (like in ASP.NET MVC), so you never have to call `kernel.Get<>` (or any other `container.Resolve<>`) yourself. In WinForms there is no such mechanism, so you have to resolve the dependencies yourself, preferably only the root dependency like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(kernel.Get<Form1>());
    }
}
```

By putting the right dependencies on your main form (probably including a factory in your case for the games), you should not need any more `kernel.Get<>` in your application.